# display multiple columns under the one header in grid view

Tags: asp.net

I am using the grid view in asp.net and i want to show the sub columns under these headers from different table in database.

Example:
Suppose **Expenditure**(Main header)

Date,Details,Amount(sub columns of expenditure)

and VAT,Charges,Repairs,Salary are the sub columns under Details field.

Kindly please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the TemplateField like this

```
<GridView>
<Columns>
<TemplateField HeaderText="YourHeader">
<ItemTemplate>
<%# Eval("DatabaseField") %> <%# Eval("DatabaseField") %> <%# Eval("DatabaseField") %>
</ItemTemplate>
</TemplateField>
<TemplateField HeaderText="YourHeader1">
<ItemTemplate>
<%# Eval("DatabaseField") %> <%# Eval("DatabaseField") %> <%# Eval("DatabaseField") %>
</ItemTemplate>
</TemplateField>
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to user a "Repeater" instead of data grid.